# differences between scrapy.crawler and scrapy.spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and quite confused about crawler and spider. It seems that both of them can crawl the website and parse items.

There are a **Crawler** class(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py) and a **CrawlerSpider** class(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py) in Scrapy. Does anyone could tell me the differences between them? And which one should I use in what conditions?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CrawlerSpider is a sub-class of BaseSpider : This is the calls you need to extend if you want your spider to follow links according to the "Rule" list.
"Crawler" is the main crawler sub-classed by CrawlerProcess.
You will have to sub-class CrawlerSpider in you spider but I don't think you will have to touch Crawler.

Comment: Does the **CrawlerSpider** use the **Crawler** when crawling?

Comment: Add to my own question: `CrawlerSpider` doesn't use `Crawler` when crawling. Usually we use `CrawlerProcess` instead of `Crawler`, it's a class to run a single Scrapy crawler in a process. It provides automatic control of the Twisted reactor and installs some convenient signals for shutting down the crawl.

Comment: Edit: `CrawlerProcess` emphasizes **scheduling a crawler to run in a process**, while `CrawlSpider` focuses on **scraping typical web sites that requires crawling pages**. So we can use `CrawlerProcess` to schedule a `CrawlSpider` to run.