# scrapy spider vs crawler differences and better use

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

what is the difference between spider and crawler?

and which one should I use? ( i mean which one provide more ffunctions )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578170/differences-between-scrapy-crawler-and-scrapy-spider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You extend the [`scrapy.contrib.spiders.crawl.CrawlerSpider`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) class when you want to create a spider that uses [rules and link extractors](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) to specify how the crawling process will work -- namely, how it should follow links to other pages.

You extend the class [`scrapy.Spider`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider) when you don't need crawling or if you just want to handle it yourself.

Comment: that is a relief thanks

Comment: @downvoters: care to comment?